# Using V-IF inside css attribute

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to use different class based on true or false. Here's my approach:

if(i == 0) assign class name d-block, else assign class name d-none

```
<div class="card :v-if='steps == 1 ? d-block ? d-none'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead

```html
<div :class="{card: 'steps === 1' ? 'd-block' : 'd-none'}"></div>
```